# Updated to VS Code 1.55.0 but no python notebook improvements

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

New to both VS Code and Python. I just updated to 1.55.0 [image]

Very excited about getting improved Python notebook functionality but so far it looks identical to previous install, no block folding, for example.

I tried disabling every extension but python and notebook to no avail. Also, have the "Insiders" version install and it looks dandy...

Any ideas?

Comment: The Jupyter function in VS Code is provided by the extension "Jupyter", and according to the content of [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/1629), this function is under discussion. If you need to use this feature, please use "Visual Studio Code Insiders".

Comment: Thanks Jill, but other features shown at https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_55#_notebooks, such as multi cell selection, different cell decoration (with collapse arrow)  also haven't appeared for me. Any ideas?

Comment: I should add that while the extension "Jupyter" provides the notebook functionality, these featured are listed/shown on the main VSCode release page for 1.55. If there's a better setting to ask this question please point me in that direction! Many hanks!

Comment: -You could ask this questions in [vscode-jupyter](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues) on Github.

Answer (score 0):

Hi there I'm a developer on the Jupyter extension. Currently our support for the new notebook UI is in the process of rolling out. If you download VS Code - Insiders (which can safely run SxS with a normal stable VS Code install) you will get the new interface by default. In stable VS Code we are only rolling out the new UI to a select few customers, but we will be rolling it out to more in the upcoming months and eventually to all stable customers.

Comment: Thanks, new interface is way better (kbd shortcuts work better too). Insiders it is for me! Thank you.